# How can I run a keyword search that targets only papers resulted from industry or industry-sponsored research?

Tags: research-process

I want to know -- if there is a way -- how I could customize my keyword searches to target research papers or other research artifacts generated by industry or industry-sponsored research?

In particular I am interested in Software Engineering. I have access to Google Scholar, Web Of Science, and Scopus so if there's a way to do this in either of these systems that I would love to hear it.

Comment: Your criteria aren't really very sharp. Much "industry" research is fundamental (in my field of computer science, much groundbreaking research was done e.g. at Bell Labs --part of AT&T-- or at IBM, or assorted other sites, not always for more or less short-term use). in Germany it is common that university research is directly funded by industry. On the other hand, "pure" non-industry research has also turned out to have very direct practical uses (just think of the private tinkering by a physicist to disseminate work-in-progress by coleages that became what today is WWW). And there is work wi

Comment: I am interested to access research done cohesively and systematically in pursuit of a technological development vision. Much of the academic research on the topic I am interested on is comprised of one-off works that are neither here nor there. Maybe the criteria is not the best, but all I am interested in at the moment is the *how*. How would I do such a search?

Comment: Search patents?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A proxy would be to search by affiliation ([link to Scopus doc](https://service.elsevier.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/11364/supporthub/scopus/), probably feasible with other tools). List companies working in the topic and search papers with at least one author affiliated to them, or possibly with the company name in text (acknowledgements).

This will miss companies you did not think about and those with weird affiliations (for instance if "Foobar Inc." has a research division "FB new stuff", the affiliation does not include the string "foobar").